# Vbscript checking array value from other server

Tags: arrays, vbscript

How can I compare array value from other server
I use vbscript but the array from other server is built in php..
below the array I received..

```
{"VALUE1":"yes","VALUE2":"success","VALUE3":"34","VALUE4":"1","VALUE5":"377"}.
```

I want to check the value for VALUE1 to VALUE4.. here my code..

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each x in Test1
  xSplit = Split(x, ":")

  dict.Add xSplit(0), xSplit(1)

Next

If dict.Exists("VALUE1") Then


  response.Write dict("VALUE1") 

Else

  response.Write( "Index VALUE1 does not exist.")

End If
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've got is a JSON string, so you need a JSON parser. 
Instead of writing your own, you can use a parser like [ASPJSON](http://www.aspjson.com/)

```vb
<!--#include file="aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
<%
Dim oJSON
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

oJSON.loadJSON(x) 'x is the JSON string

If oJSON.data.Exists("VALUE1") Then
    Response.Write oJSON.data("VALUE1")
Else
    Response.Write "Index VALUE1 does not exist."
End If
%>
```